# Keep blank cateogries in ggplot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df with a list of dates which I want to show in a bar chart by week of the year.
I need for it to display in the form of YearWeek eg 202034 and if there aren't any for that week, the bar needs to show zero.

I can plot this using just the dates and the blanks are shown:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(93)
df<-data.frame(date=sample(seq(as.Date('2020-08-01'), as.Date('2020-09-30'), by="day"), 5,replace=TRUE))
df$yearweek<-paste0(year(df$date),isoweek(df$date))

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x=`date`))
```

[image]

If I try to plot this using the year and week then any weeks where there is missing data, the bars aren't there.
[image]

How can I amend the code so it shows the blank weeks in the bar chart?

Comment: set the breaks in your axis to the weeks you would like to show.  ?scale_x_datetime() for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
Edited the answer to reflect comment.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

set.seed(93)
df<-data.frame(date=sample(seq(as.Date('2020-08-01'), as.Date('2020-09-30'), by="day"), 5,replace=TRUE))
df$yearweek<-paste0(year(df$date),isoweek(df$date))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(week_floor=lubridate::floor_date(date, unit = "week"))

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x=week_floor))+
  scale_x_date(breaks=scales::date_breaks(width = "1 week"),
               labels=scales::date_format(format="%Y%U"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The issue I have is that I need it to be formatted in a particular way eg YearWeek 202037 rather than Sep-07

Comment: @Basil see above. changed the formatting of the x axis labels

Comment: How can I aggregate the totals by week? In the above plot, even though the labelling is correct it is still plotted by day.

Comment: @Basil changed the code again. Pls see above.